# How to expand trigonometric functions of the form sin(ax)?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, trigonometric-series

I would like to expand functions of the form sin(ax), where a is an integer, to an expression only involving trigonometric functions with input x (such as sin(x), cos(x), sin(x)*cos(x), etc.).

I am aware I could do this by using each function's respective sum of angle formula, but that is a very tedious approach that can be very troublesome as "a" grows larger.

I am looking for some way to do it similar to the way (1+x)^n can be expanded by using Pascal's Triangle.

Comment: Use Euler's formula $ 2isin(n\phi)=e^{in\phi} -e^{-in\phi}$

Comment: See [Sine, cosine, and tangent of multiple angles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Sine.2C_cosine.2C_and_tangent_of_multiple_angles). It helps if you know complex numbers and [De Moivre's formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Moivre%27s_formula).

Comment: @dxiv yep Euler and De Moivre 's formula to expand sin(nx)

Answer (score 1):

$$\cos(nx) = T_n(\cos(x))$$ where $T_n$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of the first kind.
$$\sin(nx) = U_{n-1}(\cos(x)) \sin(x)$$
where $U_n$ are the Chebyshev polynomials of the second kind.